# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18472 bytes)

Tags: php, memory

I get the above error at this line:

```
imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255));
```

the script works fine with all image types, but it crashes with images that has a resolution bigger than 4000 x 3000 pixles. The image itself is only 500kb.
Here is all code:

```
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($source), imagesy($source));
imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255));
imagealphablending($canvas, TRUE);
imagecopy($canvas, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($source), imagesy($source));
imagedestroy($source);
$quality = 100; // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
imagejpeg($canvas, $strPath.$p_Id.".jpg", $quality);        //----- save image
ImageDestroy($canvas);
```

Comment: 4000 pixels x 3000 pixels @ 4 bytes per pixel = 48MB just to hold that image in memory, even before you start manipulating it, and you're copying images, so you have multiple copies of that 48MB In memory.... no surprise that you hit limits

Comment: 500KB is just the **file size** after applying lossy compression. If you need to manipulate pictures you have to allocate them in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless what is the size of the compressed image, seems your library needs more memory. I see you are using 128 mb atm, increase it to lets say 256, by using:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

Comment: Top of the script is fine.

Comment: Sure. You should accept my answer, so people stop replying :)

Answer (score 1):

I would override the default memory limit in PHP with:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless what is the size of the compressed image, seems your library needs more memory. I see you are using 128 mb atm, increase it to most

```
ini_set('memory_limit', 0);
```

Comment: The PHP doc says, it expects -1, not zero. And this answer is already provided by derdida